# Sometimes experiencing heavy load using elpy

Tags: elpy

I have a couple of times experienced an elpy (Emacs Python development environment) python process using a considerable amount of CPU resources, loading the computer to an extent that I had to kill the python process. This seems to happen if there temporarily is a syntax error in the Python file edited.

I see that the elpy Python process is also loading the computer during startup:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                          
5011 fnielsen  20   0 1926520 232172  68344 S  51.0  5.7   0:52.33 python
```

I believe my elpy setup is pretty vanilla just following https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki/Installation

What could be wrong?